# Data is automatically deleted from SQL Server CE

Tags: sql-server-ce

I am trying to write an application in VS2010 c# (Winforms) with SQL Server CE 3.5 as backend. I used the transactions for insertion of data in a table, while testing I inserted 18 rows and everything was OK.

But on the next day I found some rows missing, and when I tried to insert new rows, some primary key related error occurred. When I opened the database in SSMS and tried `@@Identity`, it returned the number 19.

I inserted a value into the database from SSMS and when I tried the application everything worked fine. Now the identity column contains values from 1 to 14 and from 19 to 25 (15 to 18 are missing).

Now I ask you experts to kindly help me to figure out the reason behind this automatic deletion of data.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **ALMIGHTY.**
  i got this the thing was that i have 14 entries in the table and when i build the project and added 5 more entries the id column reached 19 and then i cleaned the solution . which made the entries form 14 to 19 lost but the database is seeding as it is supposed to .

thanks a lot.

- List item

***Solution=new StackOverFlow().Experts.Suggestions.ToUnderstandAndApply();***

Answer (score 2):

If an INSERT fails, you can get "holes" in your identity values, no data has been "automatically" deleted.

Comment: Thanks Mr.ErikEJ , for your reply

Comment: Thanks Mr.ErikEJ ,   for your reply , i figured out that it is caused due to cleaning the solution . one thing i am still not getting that , i cleaned the solution for different application which is not tied with this project . how cleaning one solution deletes the data of another solution .(Also i am sorry for not mentioning that from 1 to 14 values are already in the database).

Comment: by the way Mr.ErikEJ what "holes" , i mean is there any example/tutorial etc defining "HOLES" . if please suggest.thanks alot.

Comment: I just mean missing values in the sequence

Comment: Sorry And Thanks a lot for your reply.